# How to properly catch exception from FirebaseAuthException

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, exception, firebase-authentication

My Editor(Vs code) keeps catching this exception even when it's already caught in my code. And the code works fine after the exception is caught.

**The exception Log**

> " Exception has occurred. PlatformException
> (PlatformException(firebase_auth,
> com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException: An
> account already exists with the same email address but different
> sign-in credentials. Sign in using a provider associated with this
> email address., {code: account-exists-with-different-credential,
> additionalData: {authCredential: {providerId: facebook.com,
> signInMethod: facebook.com, token: 0000000}, email: ######@gmail.com},
> message: An account already exists with the same email address but
> different sign-in credentials. Sign in using a provider associated
> with this email address.}, null)) "

**My Facebook Login Code**

```
Future<void> logInWithFaceBook() async {
    try {
      final FacebookLoginResult result = await _facebookLogin.logIn(['email']);
      final fbToken = result.accessToken.token;

      if (result.status == FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn) {
        final facebookCredential =
            firebase_auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(fbToken);

        await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(facebookCredential);
      }
    } on firebase_auth.FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      await fbLinkPendingCredential(e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: if(e.code=="account-exists-with-different-credential"){ ///account exists}

Comment: that's what is in the fbLinkPendingCredential(e) function, but the vscode still catches the exception, even when physically no exception actually exists because it has been caught by my code. I think this is a bug from vscode .

Comment: its common, even i handle that exception but still the debugger catches and pauses but it shouldn't, we should open a bug report i guess

Comment: oh, yes we should